# Why do two guards in laravel affect each other?

Tags: laravel, authentication, logout, guard

For my e-commerce app I use the default guard for `user` and made another one for the control panel `admin` but logging in or logging out a `user` affects the status in admin control panel as well and the opposite is true. Why is this?

Here is my auth file:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
```

Here is my admin login and logout controller:

```
public function enter(AdminLogin $admin){
        $credentials = $admin->only(['email', 'password']);
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)):
            $admin = ModelsAdmin::whereEmail($admin->email)->first();
            Auth::login($admin);
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.show');
        endif;

        return redirect()->back()->withMsg("There is A worng in your Credentials");
    }

    public function logout(){
        auth('admin')->logout();

        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
```

And here is my user login and logout:

```
public function enter(UserCheck $user){
    $credentials = $user->only(['email', 'password']);
    if(Auth::guard('user')->attempt($credentials)):
        $login = ModelsUser::whereEmail($user->email)->first();
        Auth::login($login);
        return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
    endif;
    return back()->withMsg('Sorry sir you Entered invalid Credentials');
}
public function logout(Request $request){

    Auth::guard('user')->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    $request->session()->regenerateToken();
    return redirect()->route('user.login');
}
```

Comment: I think `Auth::login($admin);` and `Auth::login($login);` are unneccessary. Because `Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)` and `Auth::guard('user')->attempt($credentials)` are create session if credentials are valid. You can redirect user inside if checks.

Comment: it worked in some cases like when login or logout in admin panel not affect on user panel but to show admin panel should login in user panel even admin credentials is true

Comment: How do you check user or admin is logged in?

Comment: @auth('admin')
                <div> Welcome {{auth('admin')->user()->name}}</div> @endauth

Comment: @auth('user')  @endauth

Comment: when i made logout in admin panel , the logout action done in user panel and admin panel couldn't logout  . this is admin logout                                                                       public function logout(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }                                                                                                                                     and this is user login public function logout(Request $request){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('user.login');
    }

Comment: You must use: `Auth::guard('admin')->logout();` and `Auth::guard('user')->logout();`.

Comment: still the same  problem , all work done but when logout in user panel  you couldn't access admin panel even you are login and the admin credientials is shown but every route you try to visit return you to login admin page again until login in user panel

Comment: oh ok , ok i found the problem middleware i made check for auth()->check not auth('admin')->check to be, thanks for help

Comment: You can write the solution in your question and mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was in the admin middleware . i made check for admin by auth()->check() it should be auth('admin')->check() because there are another middleware  for user is default so the two confilicted